# Feeding a file as input to Xilinx ML50x board

Tags: fpga, xilinx-ise

I am trying to feed a file to my ML505 board as an input and do some processing on it. I am using Xilinx ISE tool to generate the bit file and I use xmd tool to generate the ACE file to load onto the compact memory to program the FPGA.
I can see that the factory data of the compact memory contains media (images, and sound). And the demonstration plays them well.
How can I make my FPGA circuit reads the media files in the compact memory?

-Thanks